# Will upgrading PHP version affect my current site that running Drupal 6?

Tags: 6

I am going to test Drupal 8 RC, unfortunately my PHP version is too old.

It's asking for upgrade the version higher than PHP 5.5.9.

If I upgrade it to PHP 5.5.9 or latest version PHP 5.6.14, ***will it affect my current site that running Drupal 6?***

```
Your PHP installation is too old. Drupal requires at least PHP 5.5.9. See the system requirements page for more information.
```

Comment: As a side note, unless you are a programmer and want to spend the time, do not upgrade PHP to 7.x. It won't work very well. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215159/why-did-all-my-themes-disappear-in-drupal-6-x-when-i-upgraded-to-php-7/215161#215161

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As reported in [System requirements](https://www.drupal.org/requirements), Drupal 6 requires PHP 5.x, since support for PHP 4.x has been dropped by PHP maintainers; it is recommended PHP 5.2.5 or higher, but PHP 5.3.x and higher may produce errors or unexpected behavior.

So, yes, PHP 5.6.14 is going to affect your Drupal site, especially if you installed third-party modules or themes.

Bear in mind that Drupal 6 core code will not be changed, after Drupal 8 will get its first official and stable release. If they don't fix Drupal 6 code before, it will not get fixed. Once Drupal 6 code is not fixed, it is also probable third-party modules stop to get updates too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the specific version notes on PHP requirements to understand the compatibility:

https://www.drupal.org/requirements/php#all

Although PHP 5.3-5.5 are supported by Drupal 6, some contributed modules  are not  compatible with PHP 5.3 and higher  many will throw E_STRICT errors and have other errors. Your Drupal 6 in 5.5  core will work ok. However, some contrib modules and themes may have problems.

You can configure your environment to have multiple php versions if you are interested. This tutorial helped me a lot to configure my environment in my Mac http://getgrav.org/blog/mac-os-x-apache-setup-multiple-php-versions