# Why did all my themes disappear when I upgraded to PHP 7?

Tags: 6

Today I had to do some support on a Drupal 6 website and when I tried to refresh a CSS file, all the themes disappeared. When going to the theme page, nothing in the list at all. Not even the core themes.

This is a Drupal 6.x website and I am running it on my current development system which runs PHP 7.x among other things.

Why would my theme disappear like that?

Note: I tried clearly all the cache tables and click on the "Clear all Caches" and the caching is turned off in the Performance screen (so that way I know it's not that creating problems.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the official Drupal code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know specifically why your themes disappeared, but the requirements page for Drupal (https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/system-requirements/overview) states:

> Drupal 6: PHP 5.x only (5.2.5 or higher recommended). Warning: support
>   for PHP 4.x has been dropped. Drupal core should work with PHP 5.3.x,
>   but PHP 5.3.x and higher may produce errors or unexpected behavior
>   especially for contributed modules and themes.

PHP 7 is definitely not supported. You will likely find many more errors than this over time.

Comment: Oh yeah, I already fixed 3 or 4 others. It's just to do some work for a client. No time to create a computer with just PHP 5.x... I do not just have a spare computer to do that, that is.

Comment: ... What? Why do you need a spare computer to install PHP?

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours looking at the code, I finally found the problem:

There is a function in `file.inc` that uses `preg_match()` with a pattern where no delimiters are added. Whoever was maintaining that line of code, just put a '@' in front of it, instead of properly adding the delimiters.

There is the offensive line (around 1095):

```
elseif ($depth >= $min_depth && @ereg($mask, $file)) {
```

**Note:** The correct line says `@ereg()` which does not require the delimiters, so when I changed that to `preg_match()` so it works with PHP 7, the delimiters became required.

*(Notice the `@` character in there? Even with PHP 5 you'd get some kind of error message on that line without it!)*

The `$mask` variable is a regular expression, but all are missing the delimiters (for example: `"\.info$"` to search for the *theme.info* files.)

There is my proposed fix. I just add "/" before and after the mask, and just in case, escape any slash that would be appearing inside the name.

```
elseif ($depth >= $min_depth && preg_match('/' . str_replace('/', '\\/', $mask) . '/', $file)) {
```

Comment: Hacking around core is not a fix. Best to use PHP 5.x.

Comment: He! He! I've been hacking around Core since I started. It's just not perfect... I do not know how (if at all possible) to run two versions of PHP on the same computer. So I have 7.

Comment: Actually, Drupal 6 is using `elseif ($depth >= $min_depth && @ereg($mask, $file)) {`. So, the code you show has been edited from somebody, and it is not the original Drupal 6 code.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Ah, that could explain the lack of delimiters. `ereg()` has not been valid for a very long time, even in PHP 5.x, but was removed in PHP 7 so I must have changed it when I upgraded my OS to 16.04...